flutter google sign in failed in project idx
enter image description herei got error when i'm sign in flutter google in project idx

the error say: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

go to android/settings.gradle directory.
in that file , you will see a plugin{}
in that plugin{} , just add this
id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false

your settings.gradle file will look like :
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.24" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false

}

Then rebuild the application.
